# Take a type as a parameter to a function C++

Tags: c++, types, dictionary, mono, arguments

I have the following code which implements a simple Hash/Dict in C++

**Hash.h**

```
using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Hash
{
  private:
    vector<const char*> key_vector;
    vector<const char*> value_vector;
  public:
    void set_attribute(const char*, const char*);
    string get_attribute(const char*);
};
```

**Hash.cpp**

```
using namespace std;

#include "Hash.h"

void Hash::set_attribute(const char* key, const char* value)
{
    key_vector.push_back(key);
    value_vector.push_back(value);
}

string Hash::get_attribute(const char* key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < key_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (key_vector[i] == key)
        {
            return value_vector[i];
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, the only type it can take as a key/value is a `const char*`, but I want to extend it so that it can take any type (obviously only one type per hash). I was thinking about doing that by defining a constructor which takes a type as an argument, but I don't know at all how to do that in this situation. How would I do that, and how would I implement it so set_attribute is defined to take that type?

**Compiler: Mono**

Comment: Have you ever heard of templates? They're very useful.

Comment: How about `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @bitmask, I'm just learning C++, I'm implementing it just to help me learn stuff :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) to do this. [Here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/71199/hash-table-template-implementation-help) is an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifndef HASH_INCLUDED_H
#define HASH_INCLUDED_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Hash
{
  private:
    std::vector<const T*> key_vector;
    std::vector<const T*> value_vector;
  public:
    void set_attribute(const T*, const T*)
    {
        /* you need to add definition in your header file for templates */
    }
    T* get_attribute(const T*)
    {
        /* you need to add definition in your header file for templates */
    }
};

#endif
```

Please note that I have removed `using namespace std;` as it completely removes the entire point of having namespaces, especially in header files.

Edit: Also, is there any reason why you are not using std::vector's iterator to loop through its items ?