# How to take type as a parameter in C++, similar to typeid(T)

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid, typeinfo

I have checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379642/take-a-type-as-a-parameter-to-a-function-c) and other similar questions, but all the answer says that I need to use a template. However, let's say I want to implement typeid(T) from the standard library for fun. How would I be able to do that?

I tried to track down the typeinfo header in libstdc++'s repository, and I think I found the code for [typeinfo](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3ba965c0a3571219c638da1ba3ce64ed6623556e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/typeinfo), but I cannot find the constructor of typeinfo that takes type as a parameter. Where is the implementation of typeinfo that takes type as a parameter, or how do I use type as a parameter, just like how typeid did it?

Comment: There are no constructors for `typeinfo` or derived classes. All instances are static const and compiler-generated, which makes sense if you think about it: C++ does not have any means to define a type at runtime. Also, builtin operators can have behaviors you cannot duplicate with other language constructs.

Comment: so basically I cannot do something similar to typeid(T) because it is a built-in operator, just like sizeof(T)? :( Thanks, I will close the question soon.

Comment: Yes. (Also keep in mind that `T` could be a variable instead of a type there)

Comment: You may use a macro which turns `my_typeid(T)` into something similar to `my_typeid_impl<T>`.